# Far Cry doesn't start

Tags: wine, games

I downloaded uplay and I redeemed a Far Cry 4 code.  When the download was finished I pressed play and this happened:

[image: screenshot]

What can I do?

Comment: Also, is this Ubuntu Mate, or Linux Mint?

Answer (score 3):

[Far Cry has a horrible rating of "Garbage" on Wine HQ and will not run on Ubuntu](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=16531)

Unfortunately, gaming on Linux has always been a bit lacking due to lack of Linux releases. Sometimes, no matter how hard we try, we just can't get some things to work.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: if this answers your question, don't forget to click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means "yes, this answer is valid" – even if it's not the answer, you hoped for!